# Keep element fixed while Safari navigation bar collapes on iOS

Tags: css, css-position, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web site based on the [Hyde theme](http://hyde.getpoole.com/) for Jekyll.

This layout uses a fixed navigation bar on the left with 100% width. This is working fine in most situations.

In Safari on iOS, however, the height of the viewport changes while the user is scrolling as the browsers top navigation bar collapses. If this happens, the navigation bar's size is not updated until the scroll stops, leaving an area in the lower left corner that is not covered by the navigation bar:

[image: screenshot]
(Notice the text extends below the navigation bar. This screenshot was taken while the page was in motion.)

[This video](https://youtu.be/XChIbze2jwc) shows the problem in action.

Is there any way to force Safari to update the navigation bar's height while the scroll is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its an ongoing discussion. There is no real solution for this problem. https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

What you can try for your website is the following:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 18rem;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This will align the sidebar to the bottom and the text wont cut. The white bar will appear on top but it wont be too intrusive as the bottom being cut out.

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty close to a solution – the sidebar no longer scrolls for a few pixels, and the white bar on top is way easier to accept.

Comment: I wanted to wait a bit longer to see whether someone has a full solution – thanks for the reminder. On a side note: Weirdly, after fiddling with the padding a bit, Safari now also renders the background in the top left, at least most of the time. Weird, but thanks a lot!

Comment: if you update your iOS you will see the problem is gone. I am not facing this issue in iPhone 7

Answer (score 0):

Add the below styles to fix the issue

```
html,body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) you find the reference

Comment: Unfortunately, adding this didn't have any effect.