# make height 100% when toolbar hide in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile-browser

I have a `div` set to `position:fixed` which slide down upon clicking an `<img>`. When my fixed div appears it is in full screen for mobile browsers with full height. However, when I scroll, the mobile browser toolbar hides which causes my fixed div to not be full screen anymore (there is a gap at the bottom equivalent to the hidden toolbar's height).

Image of the toolbar :

[image]

I want to set this fixed div's height to 100% even when the mobile browser toolbar hides itself.

**CSS**

```
#slider{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background: #fff;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="tick" class="col-md-12">many things</div>
    <div id="slider" class="col-md-12">my slider</div>
</body>
```

Comment: please add html also. thanks

Comment: @XenioGracias demo HTML added

Comment: share live code somewhere.

Comment: It is possible to create scenario by adding snippet or somehow else?

Comment: When I scroll on my `fixed` modal like div (mobile browser) then background is being displayed below area (after auto hiding toolbar)

Comment: Hi Rejoanul, what mobile browser are we talking about ? What's your device height ?

Comment: @Jake any mobile browser. I am working on chrome in android & safari in iOS

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Have you seen this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922492/keep-element-fixed-while-safari-navigation-bar-collapes-on-ios ? The suggested solution could work for you

Comment: @jake not fixed. Tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using some css which stop hiding bottom toolbar on mobile browser.

when `fixed` div appear I add

```
$('body').css({'overflow':'hidden','position':'fixed'});
```

and when hide (remove) this div then again restore CSS

```
$('body').css({'overflow':'','position':''});
```

So when my `fixed` div appear it locked body and not even scroll. Also bottom toolbar of mobile browser never hide if user roughly scroll on `fixed` div. After that when div hide then body state restore again